# Combine List as field value in another list

Tags: sql, list, ms-access

I know I am supposed to have some kind of an idea or start to post on here for assitance; however, I am completely lost if there is a way/method to do this. I am looking to do this in either MS Access or SQL with a MS Access User Interface.
I am provided a table with fields such as the below.  The Customer_Code is left blank.  I am then provided a list of Customer_Code(s):  could be 1, could be a lot.  I need to automate populating ***List1***,  Field ***Customer_Code*** from ***List2***

***LIST 1  - Current state***

```
 Record Type    Customer_Code     Product          Label_ID     Label_Desc      Product_Desc
 ABC                              Product 1        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC                              Product 2        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC                              Product 3        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC                              Product 4        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
```

***LIST2***

```
 Customer_Code
 12345GR
 78901ZX
 54321RG
 10987XZ
```

***FUTURE / DESIRED STATE***

```
 Record Type    Customer_Code     Product          Label_ID     Label_Desc      Product_Desc
 ABC            12345GR           Product 1        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            12345GR           Product 2        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            12345GR           Product 3        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            12345GR           Product 4        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            78901ZX           Product 1        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            78901ZX           Product 2        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            78901ZX           Product 3        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            78901ZX           Product 4        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            54321RG           Product 1        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            54321RG           Product 2        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            54321RG           Product 3        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            54321RG           Product 4        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            10987XZ           Product 1        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            10987XZ           Product 2        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            10987XZ           Product 3        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
 ABC            10987XZ           Product 4        3            Short_Desc      Long Desc
```

So far all I have is a simple query 
`UPDATE [List1], [Customer_Code] SET [List1].[Customer_Code] = [List2]. [Customer_Code];`

Comment: Based on what condition do you want to update List1?

Comment: Not really a condition. It's almost like a Pivot Table. I want Table List1 Populated with the values from Table List2; almost a union query;   I need List1 to grow by the values in List2.  So in this example there were 4 records in List2; so I would want List1 to basically be duplicated 4 times with each record from List 2.

Comment: I attempted the following; but it also doesn't work: `SELECT [Record Type], [Customer_Code], [Product], [Label ID], [Label_Desc], [Product_Desc] FROM [List1] union select null as [Record Type],  , [Customer_Code], null as [Product], null as [Label ID], null as [Lbel_Desc], null as [Product_Desc] FROM [List2]`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to cross join both tables: `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM List1 As t1, List2 As t2;` Check what result this query produces...

Comment: OMGosh. I am such a ditz this morning. I was over thinking this one.  Thank you Maciej, that was exactly it. I can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Marciej answered my question.  It was very simple; I was overthinking this one:
SImple Select query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM List1 As t1, List2 as t2
```